# Which CoroutineScope to use for Spring Boot WebFlux endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, kotlinx.coroutines

In a Spring Boot WebFlux application we have a number of endpoints (REST and GraphQL) which return a `Mono` or `Flux` of something. The code that these endpoints call is all non-blocking, but rather than using reactor we'd like to write all this non-blocking code using Kotlin coroutines. We can use a method such as `kotlinx.coroutines.reactor.mono()` to wrap our coroutines in a `Mono` (and the corresponding `flux()` method for `Flux` results).

In order to call these methods, though, we first need a `CoroutineScope` to wrap the whole request (and to handle things like cancelling any child coroutines which our main "entry point" coroutine starts). There seem to be several options here. For example, we could construct a new `CoroutineScope` and choose a dispatcher, e.g. `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).mono {...`. Or we could construct our own class which represents the whole HTTP request, and have that implement `CoroutineScope`, as shown [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html) for an Android `Activity`.

Implicit within this question is the choice of what thread (or thread pool) the work should be executed on. We could create a thread pool ourselves, but Spring Boot WebFlux has already created its own thread pool for handling HTTP requests in a non-blocking environment, so maybe it's better to try to stay in the current thread (or in that thread pool)? If that is the best way to go, is there a way to get at that thread pool and get the coroutine to run on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in Spring WebFlux, HTTP exchanges are not tide to a specific thread, `GlobalScope.mono(Dispatchers.Unconfined)` is probably the best option.

Notice that `Dispatchers.Unconfined` is an experimental API, as well as Coroutines channel API that will be deeply impacted by [lazy iterable streams](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/254). So I would advise you to wait [Spring official support for Coroutines](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15413) for any production code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It says [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/) that "Application code usually should use application-defined CoroutineScope, using async or launch on the instance of GlobalScope is highly discouraged." Is there an explanation for why in this case it's OK to use `GlobalScope`? (I know we're not using `async` or `launch`, but I thought the warning about `GlobalScope` applied in general.)

Comment: Indeed, since `GlobalScope` should be used very carefully at framework level, that's why I strongly advise to wait the official support we are working on. I think we will end up with a `CoroutineScope` that will be used at HTTP exchange level, with all the error, lifecycle listeners wired correctly.

Comment: Looks like this will now be available in Spring Framework 5.2.  See [here](https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/12/going-reactive-with-spring-coroutines-and-kotlin-flow) for excellent explanation from @sdeleuze.